# Why is this attempt at single-channel audio in MATLAB failing?

Tags: matlab, audio

I am using the following code to send a tone to only one side of headphones:

```
t= 0:1/16000:5;    
chan1 = cos(2*pi*500*t)'; %500 Hz tone    
chan2 = zeros(size(chan1)); % silence    
x = [chan1 chan2]; % stereo signal    
sound(x, 16000)
```

However, I am still getting a tone from both sides of the earplug. Why is that?  It seems that the sound from the supposedly "mute side" is lower, but I can still hear it. Is it that my sound card cannot do it? I do not understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the way to go. Maybe it's your soundcard, or your headphones/loudspeakers, that don't have enough isolation between both channels.